# C ++ using multiple cores breakes output , code for a math problem

Tags: c++, math, openmp

So, for start im just starting to learn c++, and i had to resolve this problem: Find the numbers with the propriety : 5 * 5 = 25 , 25 * 25 =625(25squared), 6*6 =36(6squared) ( 25 is the ending of 625, 5 is the the ending of 25 ). So i've got my code to find all the numbers lower than 30k , but then i wanted to push it to it's limit ,so up to lluint_max, but it was really slow, i saw that my 12 core cpu is not utilised so i thought i'd add more cpu cores. I wanted to find the easiest fix and i found openmp, read a little and foun that if i add omp for it should divide the load to multiple cores, but the console doesn't display my numbers anymore.(PS i enabled omp in vs)

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int x, i, nc = 0, z = 1, p;
#pragma omp for
    for (x = 1; x <= ULLONG_MAX; x++)
    {

        //numarul de cifre a lui x
        while (x / z != 0)
        {
            z = z * 10;
            nc = nc + 1;
        }
        //patratul
        p = x * x;
        i = pow(10, nc);
        if (p % i == x)
            cout << x << endl;

    }
}
```

And heres my output:

```
C:\Users\Mihai Cazac\source\repos\ConsoleAPP2\Debug\ConsoleAPP2.exe (process 8736) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Expected output:

```
1
5
6
25
76
376
625
9376
90625
109376
890625
2890625
7109376
12890625
//and so on
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is exactly the bug described [here](http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/): Sharing variables among multiple threads.

Comment: For `#pragma omp for` to work, each iteration of the `for` loop should not be dependent on the previous one. However, `nc` is defined outside the loop, but updated inside of it via `nc = nc + 1`, so there *is* such a dependency.

Comment: Raymond Chen,  jjramsey: Would you be willing to modify the OP's code with your combined suggestions, and post it as an "answer"?  Be sure to cite this link: http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/

Comment: Start with the basic idiom of defining your variables as late as possible (where first used), rather than at the top of the function, and most (if not all) of the multithreading problems go away.

Comment: Note that for `long long int x`, the condition `x <= ULLONG_MAX` is always true. Even if you would declare `x` as `unsigned long long int x`, you would still have to compare using `<`, not `<=`, otherwise it would still be always true.

Comment: So i've read through the suggestions and posts you linked, thank you very much, and i've treid to declare all the variables as late as possible in the for function, the code still doesn't work out, i put an update for my code above.

Comment: I rolled back edits, because they made it unclear what the question was about. The info here is supposed to be clearly divided into "question" and "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've resolved it , special thanks to Raymond Chen for his comment and the blog he directed me to, http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/

This site explained it really well.
I declared the variables as late as possible, also changhed to LLInt_Max as openmp doesnt want to work with unsigned only ,idk why
Also schedule dynamic seems to divide the workload,but i may be wrong.

My final code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (long long int x = 1; x < LLONG_MAX; x++)
    {

        long long int t = x;
        int d = 0;
        while (t > 0)
        {
            t = t / 10; 
            d++;
        }

        //patratul
        long long int p = x * x;
        long long int i = pow(10, d );
        if (p % i == x)
            cout << x << endl;

    }
}
```